# Apache2 process keep running for long time, end up with full Ram and processor

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.4

I have problem with new server Ubuntu 16, it keeps opening the apache2 process for hours which fill all the RAM of server and processor to 100% usage.
I am not sure if it is because of some malware or error in configuration.

Here is the top process 
[Top process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5BWa.png)

Here are the settings in **apache2.conf**

```
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off


<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>


<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

I have 8GB RAM and 4 Processor so I think these settings are OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure this out, it was because of some extension keep running and CPU was on 100% after few minutes.

Best thing to check this using `top` command using SSH

Comment: What do you mean by "extension"?

Comment: I had some extensions on my Magento store which were cause too much load time. So best is to check the apache2 access log you will see who is accessing Apache

Answer (score 1):

Chucking a bunch of config options and some random data about your system at us isn't at all useful.

You need to apply scientific method.

- Install monitoring
- Gather data
- Use the data to help understand the system
- Make changes based on what you have learned above
- Monitor changes
- Repeat analysis and make changes as required
- Document changes

It's not rocket engineering or even alternate facts. Simple applied system management principles is all you need.

[Further reading](https://serverfault.com/search?q=user:9517%20scientific%20method)

Comment: can you recommend any monitoring app for apache?